# javascript "this" keyword not referring to correct thing

Tags: javascript, this

```
var ball = {
    x: 20,
    y: 500,
    vx: 100,
    vy: 100,
    width: 13,
    height: 13,
    draw: function() { 
        var img = new Image();  
        img.src = 'images/ball.png';  
        img.onload = function(){  
            ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y);  
        };
    },
```

I want the drawImage() line of code to refer to the ball.x and ball.y. Instead of using ball.x and ball.y, I want to use "this" keyword so that i can turn the ball object into a function that is a mass constructor/prototype if i end up wanting to (able to make ball1, ball2, ball3 etc.). I think "this" is not referring to ball anymore because it's in a nested function? Is there any way around that without hard-coding ball.x and ball.y into the drawImage arguments?

Comment: Perhaps define a property `self: this` and replace `this` with `self` in your onload function?

Comment: @jonhopkins assigning `self: this` within an object literal wouldn't work. He could use `var self = this;` within the `draw` function though.

Comment: the comma and missing `};` at the end will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks all! @pstanton that's not the last function in ball.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the tricky things about JavaScript: `this` is dynamic. To put it simply, the solution is to put the `this` you want in a variable while you have it and use that variable to refer to it:

```
var ball = {
    // ...
    draw: function() {
        // ...
        var myself = this;
        image.onload = function() {
            // use myself rather than this
        };
    }
};
```

Another solution is to fix the value of `this`. That is done using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var ball = {
    // ...
    draw: function() {
        // ...
        image.onload = function() {
            // ...
        }.bind(this);
    }
};
```

That will bind the value of `this` inside the `onload` function to whatever it was when `draw` was called. This latter solution won't work on older browsers, but it is easily shimmed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you need to use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).  All you need to do is refer to the variables by their parent instead of by the use of this, which will actually refer to the img element in the function.  So just change your code to

```
ctx.drawImage(img, ball.x, ball.y);
```

or even

```
ctx.drawImage(this, ball.x, ball.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ball = function(){
    this.x= 20;
    this.y=500;
    this.vx= 100;
    this.vy= 100;
    this.width= 13;
    this.height= 13;
}

ball.prototype = {
    draw: function() { 
       var img = new Image();  
       img.src = 'images/ball.png';  
       var balref = this;
       img.onload = function(){  
           ctx.drawImage(img, balref .x, balref.y);  
       }
}

var myball = new ball();
myball.draw();
```

Note: not tested